# List of available WiFi networks are not showing up

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on dual boot with Windows. While wireless networking works fine in Windows, Ubuntu's top-right network menu doesn't display any available wireless networks.

The only way I can access the Internet is using Ethernet.

Here is the output from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
05:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
05:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Here is the output from `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0c
       serial: 64:51:06:07:c3:0b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.0.33 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0300000-f0300fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0210000-f021ffff
```

The `network UNCLAIMED` line made me think that the driver is missing, so I have tried using `ndisgtk` to run the Windows driver for my wireless adapter, the RT3290, but it still doesn't show any wireless networks.
I am very new to Ubuntu, so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  ,particularly the Troubleshooting section, 3.1, Device Recognition and Operation?

Comment: @ubfan1 thanks, i'll follow the guide now and see if it works

Comment: I typed in `sudo iwconfig` and I got: `eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.` Which according to the guide means that I dont have a driver installed, what command can I use to check what drivers I have installed?

Comment: To properly format terminal output, select the terminal output and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Start with posting the output of

```
rfkill list
```

to ensure there is no soft or hard blocks.  Hard blocks are usually switches, soft blocks drivers.  Then

```
lsmod | sort
```

to see if the rt2800pci driver is listed (I think that's the one for your hardware).  It should be in the default install,nothing special to get it.  If it's not loading, check for any lines in any file in /etc/modprobe.d that look like:

```
blacklist rt2800pci
```

and remove or comment them out.

---

Locate the missing firmware with:

```
dmesg | grep -i firmware
```

and if it's related to the wireless hardware, install/reinstall if necessary the linux-firmware package.  worst case, download the firmware from the vendor.
Once the firmware is present and loaded, the driver should load automatically if there are no longer any blacklist lines in any files in /etc/modprobe.d.

Comment: `rfkill list` is empty and I have a blacklist-myrt2800pci.conf file inside modprobe.d, but i'm unable to save changes to it or delete it

Comment: I realise now that I may have removed some modules whilst trying to install a 3rd party driver. Here is what I did before: `modprobe -r rt2800pci
modprobe -r rt2x00pci

cp blacklist-ralink.conf /etc/modprobe.d/`

Comment: I have added the rt2800pci module back into the kernel using `modprobe rt2800pci` and I have commented out the blacklist in modprobe.d. However now the network menu says "device not ready (firmware missing)"

Comment: Also, whenever I reboot my laptop, the modules are gone from the lsmod and I have to do it again, any help would be apprectiated, thanks